# multiple criteria in a ‘if’ statement (‘and’ & ‘or’?)

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to filter the lines fits below criteria:

1. Character ‘/’ is in the line
2. Character ‘;’ is in the line
3. Character ‘e’ is in the line
4. Character ‘k’ is not in the line
5. Character ‘@’ is not in the line
6. Length of the line does not exceed 80

What I have is:

```
the_list = ['C  TEE edBore 1 1/4200;',
'Cylinder SingleVerticalB HHJ e 1 1/8Cooling 1',
'EngineBore 11/1; TDT 8Length 3Width 3',
'EngineCy HEE Inline2008Bore 1',
'Height 4TheChallen TET e 1Stroke 1P 305',
'Height 8C ;0;Wall15ccG QBG ccGasEngineJ 142',
'Height EQE C ;0150ccGas2007',
'Length 10Wid ETQ Length 10Width ',
'Stro EHT oke 1 1/8Length ',
'Stroke 1 1/4HP   JII Stroke 1 1/4HP  ',
'Stroke 1Cy QTH 7Weight ; 1/2LBS',
'Weight 18LBSLength 1 DQT Length 12Width 7',
'Width 4L 233He TTE 3Height ;Weight ',
'Width ;Height 9200;Weight 4L APO .75H.P.@;5200RPM']


for a in the_list:
    if '/' in a and ';' in a and 'e' in a and '@' not in a and 'k' not in a and len(a)<80:
        print a
```

the ‘if’ statement doesn’t looked smart. What is the good way to put it?

Comment: It is also invalid, `'#'` isn't tested against anything.

Comment: thanks Mr. Pieters. let's say it's 'k' instead of '#'..

Comment: I think that can be solved with regular expressions easily..

Comment: @MarkK: *just* `'k'` is always true. Did you mean `'k' not in a` instead?

Comment: Yes, I do mean "'k' not in a".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set); test for a strict subset with `<=` and use `set.isdisjoint()` to assert that no elements from a set are present:

```
if {'/', ';', 'e'} <= set(a) and {'@', 'k'}.isdisjoint(a) and len(a) <= 80:
```

Note the `<=` as well; otherwise a line of 80 character isn't valid, while your initial criteria stipulate that only lines that *exceed* 80 characters should be ignored.

Demo:

```
>>> for a in the_list:
...     if {'/', ';', 'e'} <= set(a) and {'@', 'k'}.isdisjoint(a) and len(a) <= 80:
...         print a
... 
C  TEE edBore 1 1/4200;
EngineBore 11/1; TDT 8Length 3Width 3
```

Comment: thanks Mr. Pieters. however it pops an error 'TypeError: can only compare to a set'. is it because I am using Python 2.76?

Comment: @MarkK: Are you sure you testing my code correctly? I ran this on Python 2.7.

Comment: Mr. Pieters, sorry. it works fine. by the way, what's wrong with sk11's below? regex could be a way but how to put it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just curious, is there any advantage of using `{'/', ';', 'e'} <= set(a) and {'@', 'k'}.isdisjoint(a)` instead of `set('/;e') <= set(a) and set('@k').isdisjoint(a)`? Also, the len should be `<=` 80 (does not exceed 80)

Comment: @mu無: in this case, there is no preference; either method would be about as fast as the other. In the case of a membership test (`something in {'a', 'b', 'c'}` and using Python 3.2 or newer, the set would be [converted to a `frozenset()` constant](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations), avoiding creating a new object every time. Because of *that* I prefer the literal notation.

Comment: @MarkK: you'd use `pat1.search(a) and not pat2.search(a) and len(a) <= 80`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) keywords:

```
for line in the_list:
    if all(ch in line for ch in '/;e') and \
            not any(ch in line for ch in 'k@') and \
            len(line) <= 80:
        print line
```

Results in output:

```
C  TEE edBore 1 1/4200;
EngineBore 11/1; TDT 8Length 3Width 3
```

Comment: thanks mu 無. it's a good way for me to learn 'all' and 'any'. but the lines ever longer than the original one...

Comment: @MarkK You can write the `if` statement in a single line (I've used 3 lines for more readability) - Just remove the \ at end of each line

Comment: however I was imaging something like "if any('/', ';', 'e') in a or ('@', 'k') in a and len(a)<80:" Does it exist?

Comment: It's a bit shorter if you write `'/;e'` instead of `['/', ';', 'e']`. Strings can be iterated over just like lists.

Comment: Apparently `'k'` is not permitted, so the 3rd line is not valid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP changed his input from `#` to `k` after its invalidity was pointed in comments. I've corrected it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use collections.Counter.

```
from collections import Counter

inc = ['/', ';', 'e']
exc = ['@', 'k']

for a in the_list:
    c = Counter(a)
    if all([c[k] for k in inc]) and not any([c[k] for k in exc]) and len(a)<80:
        print a
```

output:

```
C  TEE edBore 1 1/4200;
EngineBore 11/1; TDT 8Length 3Width 3
```

But I don't recommend it from readability. I think to do nothing is easy to see.